# Miglayout, dynamically inserting Panels

Tags: java, swing, miglayout

I'm creating a Java Swing application using MiG Layout the GUI consists of a series of lines
which are custom JPanels, I create the initial layout:

Panel x

Panel y

But later on I want to be able to inset a Panel in the middle of these and push the others down,

Panel x

Panel z

Panel y

At at the moment I am doing it by iterating through all the components in the layout and re-adding them:

```
    Map<Component, Object> constraintMap = ((MigLayout)this.getLayout()).getConstraintMap();
    Component[] allComps = this.getComponents();
    this.removeAll();
    for(Component c : allComps){
        if('met some insert condition'){
            this.add('new component to insert', new CC().wrap());
        this.add(c, new CC().wrap());
    }
    this.revalidate();
```

Although there isn't a great deal of components this feels very sub optimal, is there a better way to do it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [whathaveyoutried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: At the moment I'm doing it by Iterating through the components and changing their layout configurations to shift them down after a certain point, I just get the feeling there must be a nicer way

Comment: that's too vague a description (and sounds indeed like suboptimal :-) Please show a SSCCE (google if you don't know the abbreviation!) demonstrating what exactly you are doing.

Comment: Apologies I will edit the question

Comment: it's a start, but not an SSCCE ...

Comment: if you Need to add it always at the same place, add your Panel from the beginning, set visible to false and miglayout on hidemode3. This causes the Panel to be hidden and does not take place in layout, so that it does not take any space. if you set it to visible again, it repaints as usual